# Negating a statement with a interval

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Hi could anyone help me i am trying to negate a statement that has a interval [0,3], would it become the intervals:
[-infinity,0] and [4,+infinity]

Comment: Do you mean the complement ? It is the union of the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(3,\infty)$

Comment: not ($x\ge0$ and $x\le3$) is logically equivalent to $x<0$ or $x>3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\in\mathbb R$ but $x\not\in[0,3]$, then $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(3,\infty)$.

(To [indicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals) that one of the endpoints is to be excluded from the set,

the corresponding square bracket can be replaced with a parenthesis.)

Comment: oh yeah the circular brackets to not include the value, so the rest of it is correct?

Comment: @RomeoDuncan:  if one interval ends at $3$ or $4$, the other should start at $3$ or $4$, respectively